# Java in memory cache vs cache in KGB database

Tags: java, database, memcached

I am trying to figure out if we can cache data in java server's memory, why do we need something like in memory database like KGB? Can we just increase the size of java server's memory? What would be the disadvantage ? If we cache too much data in memory, will that hurt Garbage Collection ?

Comment: Are you asking why we need SQL-databases instead of storing variables like `new Person("Fred")`?

Comment: I asked why we prefer to cache temp data such such as calculated results that we don't want to persist in KGB cache rather than in Java's cache

Comment: I think it is OK if you can handle it perfect . You need to consider using less storage to save more infomation , you need to handle problerm with concurrency and data amounts ...

Comment: @passion Do you mean if too much memory is taken, it will affect concurrency somehow?

Comment: @GuifanLi  No , I mean you need to use minimum memory ,make it fast and ensure data ACID besides you need to guarantee a proper throughput